# Android studio not opening (windows)

Tags: android, android-studio

when i open **studio.exe** it say

> updating components
>
> the following components not installed

*But today only i downloaded standalone installer of android studio from offical website Please Help me*

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can tell you is delete everything you have related to studio and try again. A large reason Android Studio is so great is that it is generally very easy to set up. Just download and open - everything, including the SDK, comes preinstalled.

Make sure you use this link to get Android Studio - it is the official link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html